# How to partially disable click on home button in Android toolbar?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-menu

I have implemented `onOptionsItemSelected` to have control over the home button:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            if (mode) {
                reset()
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Now, when I press home, I go back to the previous fragment. What I need is, if the `mode` is true, when I click on home, to trigger **ONLY** the `reset()` function without going back to the previous fragment. If it's false, simply go back. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return `true` to say the parent that the click on the menu item is consumed.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            if (mode) {
                reset()
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```